# get first limited words from a custom post in the archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have created **custom Post type**. Now I am using **excerpt** to show some limited words in the archive page. but I am showing same posts on the homepage in a **content slider (Owl Carousel)** which is giving me problem cuz **excerpt size**.

1. So, I have decided to use **first 160 words of the post** to show on
   the **archive page**. Instead of Excerpt
2. Also, I have placed **Read more** Button and I would like to know
   how to put the link in that

.

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package
 */

 ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail alignleft" style="width:100%;">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
                    <header class="entry-header article">
                        <?php
                        if ( is_singular() ) :
                            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                        else :
                            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
                        endif;

                        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <?php arcvertex_posted_on(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                        <?php
                        endif; ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="entry-content-article">
                            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-readmore">Read More...</button>

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .Row -->
        </div>
</div><!-- .Row -->

<hr class="half-rule-breadcrumb" style="margin-top:10px;" />

<footer class="entry-footer">
<?php arcvertex_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Comment: So the problems you are having are due to the excerpt not being long enough?

Comment: No, I want to use words from the post instead of the excerpt. I am using the excerpt  for another purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a helper function built into core, [`wp_trim_words()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words), that was added in v3.3.0.

In your case, simply replace `the_excerpt()` with `echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 80 );` where 80 is the number of words you want.

Comment: could you tell me how to link read more button to post?

Comment: I would just create an `<a>` element and style it to look like a button and have it point to `esc_url( get_permalink() )` for the `src=` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add below function for character and word count in function.php

```
function wordlimit($string, $limit) 
{
    $overflow = true;
    $array = explode(" ", $string);
    $output = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) 
    {
        if (isset($array[$i])) 
        {
            $output .= $array[$i] . " ";
        }
        else 
        {
            $overflow = false;
        }
    }

    return trim($output) . ($overflow === true ? "..." : '');
}
function charlimit($string,$limit){
    $string = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $string));
    return strlen($string)<=$limit?$string:substr($string,0,$limit).'...';
}
```

then use in your file like **wordlimit(get_the_content( $post->ID ),160);** instead of **get_the_excerpt()**

```
<?php
 /**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package arcvertex
 */

 ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail alignleft" style="width:100%;">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
                    <header class="entry-header article">
                        <?php
                        if ( is_singular() ) :
                            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                        else :
                            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
                        endif;

                        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <?php arcvertex_posted_on(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                        <?php
                        endif; ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div class="entry-content-article">
                            <?php echo wordlimit(get_the_content( $post->ID ),160);?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-readmore">Read More...</button>

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .Row -->
        </div>
</div><!-- .Row -->

<hr class="half-rule-breadcrumb" style="margin-top:10px;" />

<footer class="entry-footer">
<?php arcvertex_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```